# Load my MATLAB model as a Weka model

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka

I have trained a Bayesian Regularized Neural Network model with MATLAB. This model is not available with Weka. So now I want to import my MATLAB model as Weka's `.model` file, so that I can directly use my model with Weka.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Weka can import models in the [PMML](http://www.dmg.org/v4-1/GeneralStructure.html) format, so the easiest (and possibly the only avaliable) way to load the neural network trained with some "special" form of regularization.

You will have to save your network in the PMML format, some guidelines can be obtained here:
http://www.dmg.org/v3-2/NeuralNetwork.html